# Compare text in two excel ranges, highlighting additions and strikethrough deletions

Tags: vba, excel

Code is running ok but need to be reviewed for any limitations / possible improvements. Not sure will work in all scenarios because of the number of ifs and else and length of the macro. Referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196686/comparing-2-column-ranges) on Stack Overflow.

```
Sub StringCompare2()

Dim Rg_1 As Range, Rg_2 As Range, Rg_3 As Range
Dim cL_1 As Range, cL_2 As Range, cL_3 As Range
Dim arr_1, arr_2
Dim xTxt As String, i As Long, j As Long, Ln As Long
Dim xDiffs As Boolean
On Error Resume Next

If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
    xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
End If

lOne:
Set Rg_1 = Application.InputBox("Range A:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If Rg_1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Rg_1.Columns.Count > 1 Or Rg_1.Areas.Count > 1 Then
MsgBox "Multiple ranges or columns have been selected ", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
GoTo lOne
End If
lTwo:
Set Rg_2 = Application.InputBox("Range B:", "Kutools for Excel", "", , , , , 8)
If Rg_2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Rg_2.Columns.Count > 1 Or Rg_2.Areas.Count > 1 Then
MsgBox "Multiple ranges or columns have been selected ", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
GoTo lTwo
End If

Set Rg_3 = Rg_2.Offset(0, 1)

For Each cL_3 In Rg_3
i = i + 1
If cL_3.Offset(0, -2) = "" And cL_3.Offset(0, -1) = "" Then
    cL_3 = ""
    cL_3.Interior.Color = rgbLightGray
    GoTo NextCL3
End If
If cL_3.Offset(0, -2) = "" And cL_3.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then
    cL_3 = cL_3.Offset(0, -1)
    cL_3.Font.Color = vbBlue
    cL_3.Interior.Color = rgbOrange
    GoTo NextCL3
End If
If cL_3.Offset(0, -2) <> "" And cL_3.Offset(0, -1) = "" Then
    cL_3 = cL_3.Offset(0, -2)
    cL_3.Font.Color = rgbLightGray
    cL_3.Font.Strikethrough = True
    cL_3.Interior.Color = rgbBlack
    GoTo NextCL3
End If
If cL_3.Offset(0, -2) = cL_3.Offset(0, -1) Then
    cL_3 = cL_3.Offset(0, -1)
    cL_3.Font.Color = vbBlack
    cL_3.Interior.Color = rgbLightGreen
    GoTo NextCL3
End If

arr_1 = Split(Rg_1(i, 1), " ", , vbTextCompare)
arr_2 = Split(Rg_2(i, 1), " ", , vbTextCompare)

For j = 0 To UBound(arr_1) + UBound(arr_2)
Ln = Len(cL_3)
If Ln = 0 Then
    If arr_1(j) = arr_2(j) Then
    cL_3.Value = arr_2(j)
    cL_3.Font.Color = vbBlack
    cL_3.Font.Strikethrough = False
    Else
    cL_3.Value = arr_1(j) & " " & arr_2(j)
    cL_3.Characters(1, Len(arr_1(j))).Font.Strikethrough = True
    cL_3.Characters(1, Len(arr_1(j))).Font.Color = rgbLightGray
    cL_3.Characters(Len(arr_1(j)) + 2, Len(arr_2(j))).Font.Strikethrough = False
    cL_3.Characters(Len(arr_1(j)) + 2, Len(arr_2(j))).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Else
    If j > UBound(arr_1) Then
        cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) + 1, Len(" " & arr_2(j))).Insert (" " & arr_2(j))
        cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_2(j)) + 1, Len(" " & arr_2(j))).Font.Color = vbRed
        cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_2(j)) + 1, Len(" " & arr_2(j))).Font.Strikethrough = False
    Else
    If j > UBound(arr_2) Then
        cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) + 1, Len(" " & arr_1(j))).Insert (" " & arr_1(j))
        cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_1(j)) + 1, Len(" " & arr_1(j))).Font.Color = rgbLightGray
        cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_1(j)) + 1, Len(" " & arr_1(j))).Font.Strikethrough = True
    Else

    If arr_1(j) = arr_2(j) Then
    cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) + 1, Len(" " & arr_2(j))).Insert (" " & arr_2(j))
    cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_2(j)) + 2, Len(" " & arr_2(j))).Font.Color = vbBlack
    cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_2(j)) + 2, Len(" " & arr_2(j))).Font.Strikethrough = False
    Else
    cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) + 1, Len(" " & arr_1(j) & " " & arr_2(j))).Insert _
                    (" " & arr_1(j) & " " & arr_2(j))

    cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_1(j) & " " & arr_2(j)) + 2, Len(arr_1(j))).Font.Strikethrough = True
    cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_1(j) & " " & arr_2(j)) + 2, Len(arr_1(j))).Font.Color = rgbLightGray

    cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_2(j)) + 2, Len(arr_2(j))).Font.Strikethrough = False
    cL_3.Characters(Len(cL_3) - Len(" " & arr_2(j)) + 2, Len(arr_2(j))).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
    End If
    End If
End If
Next

NextCL3:

Erase arr_1: ReDim arr_1(0)
Erase arr_2: ReDim arr_2(0)
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples that show pretty odd results:

[image]

What I would expect as result is something like

[image]

Especially here

[image]

where it says that `if` and `this` were deleted and added at the same place: `if this` should definitely be black.

[image]

---

Also here

[image]

it says every single word was deleted and replaced by something else while you could just do the following

[image]

and keep at least `to proove you wrong`. Note that this is only one possible solution and there are more than one for each comparison. To find the best solution you would need to calculate all possibilities and use a good criteria to decide which one of them would be the best one.

As I already explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58628570/how-can-i-output-the-matching-portion-of-two-strings-while-having-the-charact/58628990#58628990) the probelem to solve is **a way** more complex than you see in the first moment.

Especially if you want a *by charater* solution like the OP stated

[image]

and not a much simpler *by word* solution (as you tried).

I see no simple answer to the issue beyond what I showed in the linked answer (using the dynamic programming technique).

Comment: Totally agree with you. That was my intention to show the case of cell C9 of the screen shot I submitted. Addition of just one word at the beginning made the entire replacement as new addition as it compares word by word and not by characters. Thanks for the link.. its a good food for thought over the weekend. Though, with my limited skills in Excel/ VBA, I don't see any road further on this. Thanks.